# How to count the occurrences of a number or text in a column?

Tags: excel

What formula can I use to calculate how many times the same number appears within the column in the format of increment order like 1,2,3..

For example, when a number appear for the first time it should show 1. When it appears again it should add +1 to it.

```
111 1
111 2
333 1
444 1
555 1
666 1
777 1
888 1
666 2
777 2
888 2
666 3
777 3
888 3
666 4
```

Comment: Have you tried COUNTIF()? [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-how-often-a-value-occurs-HP001127779.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want COUNTIF() with a mixed reference:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```

The $A$1:A1 reference means if you drag the formula down the page, you will be counting the number of occurrences down to that row

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]